# A word meaning to change in outward appearance without altering the underlying substance

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m working with the Latin phrase “Esse Quam Videri” (Motto of the [BYU Men’s Chorus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BYU_choirs)) which means “to be rather than to seem.”

I want to talk about becoming (changing underlying form into something else) and to contrast that with merely seming to transform. I’d like to say “become rather than ____”. A verb would be best.

Any ideas? Thanks. :)

Comment: The word that would fit best into your blank space is ***appear***. The problem is that it has an additional meaning of *show up*.

Comment: I suggest 'seem' but really we need a complete sentence to provide real context.

Comment: My first thought is "sham", though that's more an adjective than a verb.  Brings to mind [Potemkin villages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potemkin_village).  "Facade" is a related noun: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/facade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the word that best fits here is "pretend". (Sheepish look.) I'm not sure why I didn't think of that sooner.

Thanks everyone for some really good feedback and suggests. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go with **imitate**, which means to resemble.  ie 'become rather than imitate'.

Other words that might work include emulate, mime, and mimic.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the outward appearance of something, without changing its essence or underlying nature, is often referred to as a **cosmetic change.**.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cosmetic

> 2. adjective If you describe measures or changes as cosmetic, you mean they improve the appearance of a situation or thing but do not change
>      its basic nature, and you are usually implying that they are
>      inadequate.

Comment: That is very much up the right alley. Is there a *verb* that denotes going through a cosmetic change? (I updated my question to clarify what I’m looking for.)

Comment: I think you need to edit your question again to include a full sentence with the blank word.

Answer (score 0):

A change only on the surface, but not more meaningfully, is a [**superficial**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superficial) change.

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2a** : concerned only with the obvious or apparent : SHALLOW
> **b** : seen on the surface : EXTERNAL
> **c** : presenting only an appearance without substance or significance

This word can apply to not only physical appearance but also to ideas and concepts.